# Windows 11: MS Word 365 spellcheck underline colour changed in registry reverts to default colour

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, windows-registry, spell-check, underlining

I have a problem with the red underlining to show spelling errors in Word. As I am translating documents, I have whole chunks of text that are in the source language and thus underlined in red. This makes the text difficult to read so I have changed the underline colour by adding a registry entry as per instructions found online. This worked fine until my pc was upgraded to Windows 11. Now, the underline colour sometimes reverts to red even though the registry entry is still there. I need to be able to use the underlining in order to quickly see mistakes or untranslated words. Does anyone know if the registry hack needs updating or has been circumvented by Microsoft?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a link to the instructions you followed and show an export of the registry entry *as text*.

Comment: Which registry hack?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-spelling-underline-colour-has-gone-back-to/00739fe3-912e-45ad-b871-baea76cadf56  ....  Please read:  A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184.

Answer (score 0):

### I suggest using language-specific character styles.

*This does not address the problems with Windows 11, of which this is but one, but should allow you to get your work done.*

The method of creating such styles in shown in my article on the Microsoft Answers site: [Using Styles for Proofing Language Settings.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-styles-for-proofing-language-settings/0a1bbf21-eaac-4044-afe6-253bfc47d65f)

You could add a shading color or a specific-color underline to such styles to draw your attention back to the untranslated words. Once translated, select and press Ctrl+Spacebar to remove the character style.